# Compiling GWT project using GUICE with ANT

Tags: gwt, ant, guice, gwt-gin

I can successfully compile the source, but when I hit this ant task:

```
  <target name="gwtc" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
      <arg line="${gwt.args}"/>
      <arg value="com.jwavro.jaguar.jaguar"/>
    </java>
  </target>
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
gwtc:
   [java] Compiling module com.jwavro.jaguar.jaguar
   [java]    Scanning for additional dependencies: generated://9161C2B729E3521B2A51CBE6F2AE8A77/com/unnison/framework/client/GeneratedGinInjector.java
   [java]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.unnison.framework.client.GeneratedGinInjector'
   [java]          Rebinding com.unnison.framework.client.GeneratedGinInjector
   [java]             Invoking generator com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator
   [java]                [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.unnison.framework.client.GeneratedGinInjector'
   [java] com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
   [java]
   [java] 1) No implementation for javax.inject.Provider was bound.
   [java]   while locating javax.inject.Provider
   [java]     for parameter 9 at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.(BindingsProcessor.java:209)
   [java]   at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGeneratorModule.configure(GinjectorGeneratorModule.java:59)
```

GUICE binding is supposed to be automatic, any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Guice can not be used directly with GWT. You need to use [GIN](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/).

Comment: The question was tagged with Gin, so I'm *hoping* he already knew that :-)

Comment: Though now that I'm looking at the question, I see that it was edited, so maybe the original posting wasn't tagged with Gin.

Answer (score 0):

[javax.inject](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/05/javaxinjectinject.html) is a dependency that needs to be in your classpath.

If you [downloaded Guice from Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/list), there should be a lib folder in the exploded zip with a javax.inject.jar file, or you can [download it direct from trunk](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/#svn/trunk/lib).

The key is this line:

```
[java] 1) No implementation for javax.inject.Provider was bound.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I can think of. First of all make sure you have properly inherited the GIN module in your GWT module xml:

```
<module>
  ...
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>
  ...
</module>
```

Secondly you have to be carefull about versions of GIN and Guice. On the GIN homepage it says:

***GIN 1.0** requires ... and **Guice 2.0***

*For **Gin 1.5** you'll need to use the **Guice snapshot** distributed with Gin or ... **Guice 3.0***

So make sure you have the appropriate Guice JAR in path.